# Variable/infinity type arguments for generic class in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, events

In TypeScript, we can have generic classes like in C#:

```
export class MyClass<T> { }
```

But is it possible to pass a variable number of generics as argument? I mean something like

```
function withVariableArgs(...args: any[]){  }
```

However I lke to have this as generic (pseudo code)

```
export class MyClass<...args:any[]> { }
```

so that I could do `new MyClass<number,string>` neither `new MyClass<number>`. Is this possible in TS?

### Background: Generic typed events

I want to have a generic event-handler, which let me provide strongly types for the events. [This typesafe EventEmitter](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/typed-event.html) is only fine for a single type. Sometimes I need to pass multiple types, like a string *and* integer in the same event. Using this handler, the only possibility seems to create an interface

```
  interface EventArgs{
      id:number,
      name:string
  }
```

and then use this a type like `let event = new TypedEvent<EventArgs>()`. For complex types, defining such a model seems good practice. Thought if we have only two or three types, I think this is overkill and cause growing complexity without providing additional value. It would be great to simply create a event like `let event = new TypedEvent<number,string>` and do `event.emit(1, 'test')` without the need for creating a model and instance them.

Answer (score 3):

As an extension to @Shane response, you can use spread operator with tuples.
https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897

```
class TypedEvent<T extends any[]> {
    public emit(...args: T): void { /* ... */
    }
}
const eventHandler = new TypedEvent<[string, number]>();
eventHandler.emit("1", 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

There are no variadic types in Typescript. It has been proposed **many** times. However, you can sort of get what you want it to do with a tuple type.

If this is your event handler...

```
class TypedEvent<T>
{
    public emit(args: T): void { /* ... */ }
}
```

... you can do something like the following:

```
const eventHandler = new TypedEvent<[string, number]>();

eventHandler.emit(["1", 1]);
```